# package to switch on or off 3g and wifi on Android

Tags: android-wifi

Can anyone please tell me which SDK packages are used for switching on or off 3g and wifi on Android devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help with 3G (I know the procedure is different between CDMA and GSM networks) but for Wifi, look into the [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class for handling that sort of thing. For example, you could use this to toggle Wifi on and off:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(!wifi.isWifiEnabled());
```

EDIT: The package is `android.net.wifi`